# Was JKR alluding to a specific song?

Tags: harry-potter

JKR wrote the following;

> Accidents have occurred, however; two Muggle dog-walkers found
> themselves accidentally transported to a Celestina Warbeck concert in
> 2003, because their dogs had run off with an old trainer on Clapham
> Common (leaving an anguished crowd of witches and wizards to look
> frantically for their Portkey on a stretch of empty grass, hopefully
> seizing old crisp packets and cigarette ends). **One of the Muggle
> dog-walkers was even invited on stage by Celestina to perform a duet
> of ‘A Cauldron Full of Hot, Strong Love’. While the Memory Charm
> placed upon him by a harried Ministry official seemed to take at the
> time, he has since written a popular Muggle song that bears an uncanny
> resemblance to Celestina’s worldwide hit (Ms Warbeck is not amused).**
>
> <sub><sup>[Writings by JKR - Portkeys](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/portkeys)</sup></sub>

Is JKR referring to a real-world song as background for this joke?

Comment: https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/A_Cauldron_Full_of_Hot,_Strong_Love - Lyrics here if that's any help

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MRsCkIuOpZM

Comment: Why 1960s? The quote states that the incident took place in 2003.

Comment: At least the version performed at The Wizarding World of Harry Potter is largely generic rhythm changes, so one could probably find many real world jazz numbers that are similar. I suspect the answer to the question is “no”.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - Paul McCartney famously came up with the lyrics for [Getting Better](https://www.the-paulmccartney-project.com/song/getting-better/) while out walking his dog with a friend - "*I would go to Paul’s house at four o’clock in the afternoon and I would have tea with him, muck around and go for a walk. I remember once, I was walking around Primrose Hill with Paul and his dog Martha one spring morning. It was the first spring-like morning of that year, and as we got to the top of the hill, the sun came up. He turned to me and said, ‘It’s getting better,’ meaning that spring was here".*

Comment: @Valorum While I was posting the question I was listening to the 1960s golden hour on the radio and my brain morphed over!

Comment: @DannyMcG - I actually rather suspect that the story above is the inspiration for her writing. Possibly the song reference is '*[A Shot of Rhythm and Blues](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4VgvJj4EBpc)*"

Comment: @ToddWilcox - oops. I meant F1Krazy

Comment: @F1Krazy I don't recall this from the books, but according to the linked Wiki in the comment the Weasly parents danced to the song when they were eighteen, which  I think would actually put the song into the 60s.

Comment: I'd know a song in the mix if 1972 were in the date range...